# What is the best way to share events between Google cloud run containers

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a service which is running on many cloud run containers.

When a single container (A) receives a web request to do some work, I need all the other live containers to fetch some updated data from elasticsearch.

I would have expected ES to have a "listening" type of connection such as firebase but this is not possible.

Right now I am having to poll the database from each service.

Is there a better way to achieve this sort of cross container sync when using cloud run? Would pub/sub be the best solution here?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to update all the instances of the same service on Cloud RUn on a specific event?

Comment: You have no control over individual containers running within the **same** Cloud Run service. If you mean separate services, edit your question to clarify what you have deployed.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes precisely!

Comment: @JohnHanley I mean separate containers, and I am aware that I have no control over them. They are scaled automatically etc. However there are still ways to achieve what I need to happen, polling at one end, some sort of shared messaging on the other :)

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual but not impossible to achieve.

First of all, you have to understand the instance life cycle: the CPU is allocated only when a request is being processed. Else, the CPU is throttle ( bellow 5%). That's also for that you pay only when your instance is processing, and not when the instance is kept warm (and offloaded after a while).

That being said, it's totally useless and inefficient to update instances in background when a request is not being processed.

Therefore, the idea is to perform something when the instance receive a request. The bad thing is that this solution will increase the request latency (the instance start to sync his cache and then process the request).

Finally the solution is to store, somewhere, the latest cache update. You have to keep that pretty same information in your instance. When the instance receive a request, first thing, it compares its own cache date with the central data date.

- If it's the same, no problem, continue the processing.
- If the central data date is after the current instance date, update the instance data, and then process the request.

You can store the data, and the date of that data in Firestore for instance, or in MemoryStore, or in any other databases.

---

PubSub can be also a solution but more complex to implement. Each instance, when they start have to create a pull subscription on a topic. When the instance is killed, you have to delete that subscription.

Then, when a request comes in, your instance have to pull the subscription, and get the messages, if any, and update his local cache.

Could be faster than the previous solution, but harder to implement.